# this.$initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, bridge.net

I have recently started using [Bridge.NET](http://bridge.net/) and I run into a problem.

With a class defined as follow

```
public class DomEngine
{
    public DomEngine()
    {
        // Empty constructor to make sure it works
    }

    /* Lots of irrelevant code removed */
}
```

and an index.html like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MenuGeneratorFromDom</title>

    <script src="bridge.js"></script>
    <script src="bridge.console.js"></script>
    <script src="bridge.meta.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="MenuGeneratorFromDom.js"></script>
    <script src="MenuGeneratorFromDom.meta.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>1.0</h1>
    <h4>4.0</h4>
    <h2>2.0</h2>
    <h3>3.0</h3>
    <h4>4.1</h4>
    <h3>3.1</h3>
    <h3>3.2</h3>
    <h2>2.1</h2>
    <h3>3.3</h3>
    <h3>3.4</h3>
    <h4>4.2</h4>
    <h4>4.3</h4>
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        var domEngine = MenuGeneratorFromDom.DomEngine();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a `this.$initialize is not a function` in the code generated by Bridge.NET

```
Bridge.define("MenuGeneratorFromDom.DomEngine", 
{
    ctors: 
    {
        ctor: function () 
        {
            this.$initialize(); // Here
        }
    },
    /* lots of generated code */
}
```

While the `Initializ()` is, indeed, defined in `bridge.js` with the line

```
prop.$initialize = Bridge.Class._initialize;
```

(where `Bridge.Class._initialize` is defined as well) and we can see in the index.html above that `bridge.js` is included in the file before `MenuGeneratorFromDom.js`

I do not understand why this `Initialize` call throws an undefined error while it is obviously defined ! Did I forget to do something with Bridge.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add the `new` keyword in your call. You are calling `DomEngine()` like a static method, but it is a constructor.

```
// Fail
var domEngine = MenuGeneratorFromDom.DomEngine();

// Success!
var domEngine = new MenuGeneratorFromDom.DomEngine();
```

Here's a simple Deck demonstrating the scenario:

https://deck.net/847bdcf3ee52dbc3297310507d5b15d3

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! You might be right, but in the mean time I re-did my re-factor after having reverted using git and it worked. But since your answer seem to make a lot of sense I'll tag you as answering my question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(({}).toString.call(this.$initialize).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase());`.

This should output the type of this.$initialize

If it is undefined, then it is never set. If it's something other then you might have to look on the line, where the function gets initialized and deep into the right-hand value.

Comment: Thank you for your attention ! Even tho the error is now fixed, could you explain to me what this code does please ? I'm not sure I really understand it ...

Comment: Yes. It basically just outputs you the Typename of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I reverted my repository to before the re-factoring that led to this error. I re-did the re-factoring, compiling between every step and checking that the code still work every time. The error did not come back so I don't really know what caused this ?

The error fixed itself, so thanks for the attention anyway :-)